# Python list.append as an argument

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Why does the following code give 'None'? How can I resolve this?

```
def f1(list1):
    f2(list1.append(2))

def f2(list1):
    print(list1)

f1([1])
```

What also doesn't work:

```
def f1(list1):
    arg1 = list1.append(2) 
    f2(arg1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. If you want `list1` to have changed after a call to `f1`, use

```
def f1(list1):
    list1.append(2)
    f2(list1)
```

See what happens:

```
>>> l = [1]
>>> f1(l)       # Modifies l in-place!
[1, 2]
>>> l
[1, 2]
```

If you don't want `list1` to be changed:

```
def f1(list1):
    f2(list1 + [2])
```

Now see this:

```
>>> l = [1]
>>> f1(l)       # Leaves l alone!
[1, 2]
>>> l
[1]
```

Answer (score 7):

In general, Python methods that mutate an object (such as `list.append`, `list.extend`, or `list.sort`) return `None`.

If you wish to print out the new list:

```
def f1(list1):    
    list1.append(2)
    f2(list1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot.

Comment: Alternately, write an expression that produces the modified list as a separate value. For example, `f2(list1 + [2])`.